# Make radio button list clickable without js in browser, used asp webforms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, event-handling

I have function that hides or displays divs, depending on  radio button list value. My problem is that, it won't work without javascript enabled in browser. How could I get it work on server side, because SelectedIndexChanged can't get postback in this case.
I tried to add some click events to buttons, also tried prerender radio button list but no luck.

HTML:

```
<script> 

function HideOrDisplayDisvsWithRadioButton(radioButtonList) {

            var rblValue = $('#RblParticipantsType input:checked').val();
            var divInsertPerson = $('div#DivInsertPerson');
            var divInsertCompany = $('div#DivInsertCompany');

            if (rblValue === '1') {
                divInsertPerson.css('display', 'inherit');
                divInsertCompany.css('display', 'none');
            }

            if (rblValue === '2') {
                divInsertPerson.css('display', 'none');
                divInsertCompany.css('display', 'inherit');
            }
            return false;
        }
<script>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList"                                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    onchange="javscript: HideOrDisplayDisvsWithRadioButton(this)" 
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    ClientIDMode="Static"
                    RepeatColumns="2"
                    runat="server"
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Eraisik</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Ettevõte</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And code behind:

```
protected void RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                DivInsertPerson.Visible = true;
                DivInsertCompany.Visible = false;
            }

            if (RadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "2")
            {
                DivInsertCompany.Visible = true;
                DivInsertPerson.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it work with using CSS, I do not know is it wrong or right, but it works. I did something like here. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_radio) . These hidden buttons helped me out. Some configurations for CSS, HTML and C#.